# Get and set value on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working in ASP.Net MVC4. My `div` elements contents are generated in a loop as below:

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    <div class="col-md-2 vcenter">
        <span class="product-price">Preço: @Model.Price.ToString("C")</span>
    </div>

    @if (Model.IsValid != null && Model.IsValid != "")
    {
        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: end;">
            <span>Enter number.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 vcenter" style="text-align: end;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CouponTemp, new { 
                @class = "product-discount-coupon", 
                chart_price = Model.Price.ToString(), 
                dicsount_price = Model.SpecialPrice.ToString(), 
                product_coupon = Model.Coupon, 
                style = "width:50px;" 
            })
            <button type="button" class="apply-discount">Recalculate</button>   
        </div>
    }
}
```

JavaScript portion

```
$(".apply-discount").on("click", function () {
    var applyCoupon = $(this).parent().find(".product-discount-coupon").val();
    var price = $(this).parent().find(".product-price").val();
    var cost = 0;
    if (applyCoupon === NaN) {
        applyCoupon = 0;
    }

    if (price === NaN) {
        price = 0;
    }
    $(this).parent().find(".product-price").val(applyCoupon);
});
```

Browser generated html is below

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <img src="/Astrology/Product/GetImage/51da66b7-3cb9-418b-ae9a-bc9fe8073b26" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" alt="Mapa Natal C&#225;rmico" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 vcenter">
        <span style="font-size: large">Mapa Natal C&#225;rmico. Escrito por Marcelo Dalla</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 vcenter">
        <span class="product-price">Preço: R$ 44,00</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 vcenter" style="text-align: end;">
        <button type="button" class="dec-count">-</button>

        <input chart-price="44,0000" class="product-count" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." dicsount-price="10,0000" id="products_7819060a-0f29-4637-83de-9262beb1a13f__Quantity" name="products[7819060a-0f29-4637-83de-9262beb1a13f].Quantity" product-coupon="10" readonly="readonly" style="width:50px;" type="text" value="1" />
        <button type="button" class="inc-count">+</button>
    </div>

        <span>If you have a discount coupon for the purchase please enter it here and press the recalculate button.</span>
        <div class="col-md-2 vcenter" style="text-align: end;">

            <input chart-price="44,0000" class="product-discount-coupon" dicsount-price="10,0000" id="products_7819060a-0f29-4637-83de-9262beb1a13f__CouponTemp" name="products[7819060a-0f29-4637-83de-9262beb1a13f].CouponTemp" product-coupon="10" style="width:50px;" type="text" value="" />
            <button type="button" class="apply-discount">Recalculate</button>

            <input id="apply-product-coupon" type="hidden" name="apply-product-coupon">
        </div>

    <div class="col-md-1 vcenter">
        <a href="/Astrology/Shop/DeleteFromCard?productId=41f7e40b-62ad-4202-964a-cbed7381b06c">
            <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

When the user clicks on the `Recalculate` button I want to put `CouponTemp` textbox value in another `span`. Note that clicking on `block-1` does not impact on `block-2` or rest, in the same way click on `block-2` not impact on another block content.

```
<span>Preço: @Model.Price.ToString("C")</span>
```

Comment: it will be easier if you show rendered html

Comment: teo van kot,Thanks for your reply. I know how to show or use partial in mvc,will you plz show some context or code.How render html can solve my issues.

Comment: F12 in browser when you get your partial View

Comment: teo van kot, rendering is not my problem.please read my question.want to  put one div content value to another div content element.

Comment: You can use js for this. But if you want right script from us it's better to put your markup in question

Comment: @shamim - teo is asking for you to show the HTML after it's displayed in the browser (right click > view source) so we can see what the output is after your razor renders.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button.apply-discount").click(function(){
      //get your input value
      var discount = $(this).prev('input.product-discount-coupon').first().val();
      //Get your span
      var resultSpan = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().find('span');
      //Update your span with input value
      resultSpan.html("Preço: R$ " + discount);
   });      
});
```

I create [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pt8k54v7/1/) to show how it works.

Comment: @shamim i recommend you to ask another question where you describe all details of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet may help you.

```
$(".apply-discount").on("click", function () {
    var applyCoupon = $(this).parent().find(".product-discount-coupon");
    var price = applyCoupon.val();

    //to get others info
    var chart_price= applyCoupon.attr('chart_price');
    var dicsount_price= applyCoupon.attr('dicsount_price');
    var product_coupon= applyCoupon.attr('product_coupon');

    $(this).parent().prev().prev().find(".product-price").html('Preço: '+price*1);
});
```

**N.B:** price*1 will convert it to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Well, pretty easy if you just assign ids to the elements. Use something like id from your `product` to ensure they are unique and match.

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    <div class="col-md-2 vcenter">
        <span>Preço: @Model.Price.ToString("C")</span>
    </div>

    @if (Model.IsValid != null && Model.IsValid != "")
    {
        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: end;">
            <span id="@product.Id">Enter number.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 vcenter" style="text-align: end;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CouponTemp, new { 
                @class = "product-discount-coupon", 
                chart_price = Model.Price.ToString(), 
                dicsount_price = Model.SpecialPrice.ToString(), 
                product_coupon = Model.Coupon, 
                style = "width:50px;",
                id = "txt_" + @product.Id 
            })
            <button type="button" class="apply-discount" onclick="adjustPrice(@product.Id);">Recalculate</button>   
        </div>
    }
}
```

Then have a function that handles it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var adjustPrice = function (id) {
          var txt = $('#txt_' + id).val();

          $('#' + id).val(txt);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: ragerory, thanks for your reply. id can not solve my issues because need to put value on above span,which one place on another div.please look carefully my question.

Comment: @shamim I've looked at your question carefully, and I suppose I'm not understanding what you mean. Can you please provide some more clarification on how utilizing the id attribute in the manor I suggested would not fix your problem?